# Incomprehension about the first example in Rails' Guide for action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I am trying to add the User Appearances example (from the Rails' Guide : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#example-1-user-appearances ) in my app but I don't understand this part :

```
# app/channels/appearance_channel.rb
class AppearanceChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    current_user.appear
  end

  def unsubscribed
    current_user.disappear
  end

  def appear(data)
    current_user.appear(on: data['appearing_on'])
  end

  def away
    current_user.away
  end
end
```

If someone has an explanation for the following sentence : "*That appear/disappear API could be backed by Redis, a database, or whatever else.*" (Just above this part of code in the Rails' Guide).

I try several options, as adding a method "appear" in my model User which change on "true" a database value from my model User, but the subscribed definition call current_user.appear and then the appear definition call current_user.appear(with_param) generates a conflict ...

There is probably something I don't understand but I don't see exactly what is it ...

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence about "appear/disappear API backing" - means that ActionCable does not care where and how you are storing and handling users statuses - you may store only a flag or more data in database (like last seen chatroom, last seen time etc.), you may store similar data in redis or any other place you like.

`(un)subscribed` methods are caller by ActionCable itself upon user (dis)connection to that channel(usually this happens on page load and after navigating away/closing - and while page is open in browser it does not necessary mean that user is actually near their device), while `appear`/`away` are actions that are called from clientside js via calling `perform("action_name_here")` on the channel.
Example assumes that clientside code will detect user presence and send updates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to be more clear for me now.